# How to get selected/focused item or it's index in VerticalGridFragment class of Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, leanback

I need to get the selected/focused item's index of the VerticalGridFragment. I found the method to set the selected item in the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/VerticalGridFragment.html,
i.e. **setSelectedPosition(int position)** which Sets the selected item position.

But I couldn't find any method in documentation which provides the selected Item or it's index.

**Can someone please help me to find a work around to get the selected item of a VerticalGridFragment?**

Comment: why cant you use clickListener for that particular item

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I can't use that because I need to perform some operation if first row of the verticalGridFragment is focused and user presses some key. I don't need to perform the same action for all items.

Comment: if you use some flag in list<model>, will this help ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Seem you need a global variable to store selected position, and this `setOnItemViewSelectedListener` is fired when an item is selected. See [docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/VerticalGridFragment.html#setOnItemViewSelectedListener(android.support.v17.leanback.widget.OnItemViewSelectedListener))

Comment: @NamNH I want the index or item. Please have a look at the question again.

Comment: I think the `row` or `item` is enough, you can get position of them from your `adapter` or your `list` objects ? I just give the idea, because I did not working with this `class` before. You can look in the params of  `onItemSelected` method from the `interface`

Comment: use  arrayObjectAdapter.getIndex(object) will  give you index of selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the focusing position but you can get the focusing object. Below mothod `setAdapter(mAdapter);` you can write:

```
setOnItemViewSelectedListener(new OnItemViewSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item, RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
            Object object = (Object) item;
            //can write somethings here
        }
    });
```

Comment: We can get the position. Do not provide misleading fact please!

Answer (score 6):

You get selected item position .

```
private final class ItemViewSelectedListener implements OnItemViewSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item, RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
            int position=  mAdapter.indexOf(item);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `OnItemViewSelectedListener` interface in Leanback for receiving notifications when a row or item becomes selected.

See the concept of the current selection is different than focus.  A row or item can be selected without having focus. For example, when a row header view gains focus then the corresponding row view becomes selected.

mRowsAdapter is your `ArrayObjectAdapter`, few castings are required to get the current row index and current item index.

So first you get the rows adapter and by casting your rows adapter to ArrayObjectAdapter you get the adapter(which is nothing but rows adapter only) that is holding items in these rows.

```
       OnItemViewSelectedListener { itemViewHolder, item, rowViewHolder, row ->

            val indexOfRow = mRowsAdapter.indexOf(row)
            val indexOfItem = ((row as ListRow).adapter as ArrayObjectAdapter).indexOf(item)
            Toast.makeText(context, "$indexOfItem-$indexOfRow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get selected/focused item or it's index in leanback fragment,

```
setOnItemViewSelectedListener { itemViewHolder, item, rowViewHolder, row ->
            if (item is AssetData) {
                val indexOfItem = ((row as ListRow).adapter as ArrayObjectAdapter).indexOf(item)
                selectedPosition!!.getItemPosition(indexOfItem)
            }
        }
```